# Why does raising an exception invoke __subclasscheck__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, cpython

Consider the following example that uses [`__subclasscheck__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#class.__subclasscheck__) for a custom exception type:

```py
class MyMeta(type):
    def __subclasscheck__(self, subclass):
        print(f'__subclasscheck__({self!r}, {subclass!r})')

class MyError(Exception, metaclass=MyMeta):
    pass
```

Now when raising an exception of this type, the `__subclasscheck__` method gets invoked; i.e. `raise MyError()` results in:

```
__subclasscheck__(<class '__main__.MyError'>, <class '__main__.MyError'>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    raise MyError()
__main__.MyError
```

Here the first line of the output shows that `__subclasscheck__` got invoked to check whether `MyError` is a subclass of itself, i.e. `issubclass(MyError, MyError)`. I'd like to understand why that's necessary and how it's useful in general.

---

I'm using CPython 3.8.1 to reproduce this behavior. I also tried PyPy3 (3.6.9) and here `__subclasscheck__` is *not* invoked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is a CPython implementation detail. As stated in documentation to [`PyErr_NormalizeException`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html#c.PyErr_NormalizeException):

> Under certain circumstances, the values returned by `PyErr_Fetch()`
> below can be “unnormalized”, meaning that `*exc` is a class object but
> `*val` is not an instance of the same class.

So sometime during the processing of the raised error, CPython will normalize the exception, because otherwise it cannot assume that the value of the error is of the right type.

In your case it happens as follows:

- Eventually while processing the exception, [`PyErr_Print`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html#c.PyErr_Print) is called, where it [calls](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/564cd187677ae8d1488c4d8ae649aea34ebbde07/Python/pythonrun.c#L672) `_PyErr_NormalizeException`.
- `_PyErr_NormaliizeException` [calls](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/113e2b0a07c72c0d5e3489076afb14f6b3ad1049/Python/errors.c#L320) `PyObject_IsSubclass`.
- [`PyObject_IsSubclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_IsSubclass) uses `__subclasscheck__` if it is provided.

I cannot say what those "certain circumstances" for "`*exc` is a class object but `*val` is not an instance of the same class" are (maybe needed for backward compatibility - I don't know).

---

My first assumption was, that it happens, when CPython ensures (i.e. [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2b05361bf7cbbd76035206fd9befe87f37489f1e/Python/ceval.c#L4501)), that the exception is derived from `BaseException`.

The following code

```py
class OldStyle():
    pass

raise OldStyle
```

would raise `OldStyle` for Python2, but `TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not type` for

```py
class NewStyle(object):
    pass

raise NewStyle
```

or  `TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException` in Python3 because in Python3 all classes are "new style".

However, for this check not `PyObject_IsSubclass` but [`PyType_FastSubclass`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e822e37946f27c09953bb5733acf3b07c2db690f/Include/pyerrors.h#L58) is used:

```
#define PyExceptionClass_Check(x)                                       \
    (PyType_Check((x)) &&                                               \
     PyType_FastSubclass((PyTypeObject*)(x), Py_TPFLAGS_BASE_EXC_SUBCLASS))
```

i.e. only the `tpflag`s are looked at.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough investigation. Indeed it seems to be `_PyErr_NormalizeException` that performs the subclass check, however it is also triggered when I use `except MyError`, i.e. without printing the exception. I'd like to better understand under what circumstances `PyErr_Fetch()` can return an "unnormalized" exception. I suppose such situations cannot be created from pure Python code? But then isn't it the responsibility of the C extension to ensure everything is set correctly? Also I'm not sure if this can be considered an implementation detail, since it executes arbitrary user code.

Comment: @a_guest Obviously, `PyErr_Print` is not the only place where `_PyErr_NormalizeException` is called, it happens also e.g. in `exception_unwind` (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2b05361bf7cbbd76035206fd9befe87f37489f1e/Python/ceval.c#L3802), which is used when there is `except MyError`.

Comment: @a_guest "But then isn't it the responsibility of the C extension to ensure everything is set correctly". It is not, and that is the implementation detail I'm talking about.

Comment: So I guess that answers the first part of my question ("why that's necessary"; since `PyErr_Fetch` might return a non-instance, not-None value, although this is not explicitly documented). However I'd also like to understand "how this is useful in general", i.e. why would the Python C-API allow an extension to provide unnormalized exceptions? What's the use case for that? Also since the *behavior* is different for CPython and PyPy, one of them must be wrong, and given that this subclass check is not part of the Python specs, it seems to be CPython. Do you agree with that?

Comment: @a_guest The documentation doesn't say  `PyObject_IsSubclass`  will be called while an exception is proceeded but it also doesn't guarantee that `PyObject_IsSubclass` won't be called. So behavior of both, CPython and PyPy, is Ok from my point of view - the differences are implementation details. I don't know why it is useful, maybe it was needed for backward compatibility - the exception handling was quite different some time back.

Comment: I've inspected the git history a little and the introduction of `_PyErr_NormalizeException` dates back to [1997](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/c0dc92af) whereas [`__subclasscheck__`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/) was introduced in 2007. So this interaction was probably never thought of. And admittedly it's quite a niche case. However in [this commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/74a7fa66) it was noted that *"PyObject_IsSubclass() can fail and raise a new exception"* so I'm really wondering why they're not using `PyType_FastSubclass` instead.

Comment: I remember that in Python 2 you could raise an exception in the following way: `raise ValueError, 'some message'`. Perhaps that was the use case for normalization. Anyway thanks for your investigations, it definitely helped to pinpoint the source of this subclass check.

Comment: Indeed the [Python 2 specs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement) seem to confirm that: `raise_stmt ::=  "raise" [expression ["," expression ["," expression]]]`; *"If the first object is a class, it becomes the type of the exception. The second object is used to determine the exception value: If it is an instance of the class, the instance becomes the exception value. [...] any other object is treated as a single argument to the constructor [of the exception type]. The instance so created by calling the constructor is used as the exception value."*.

Comment: @a_guest `PyType_FastSubclass` can be used only for some predefined classes (list of predefined classes: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c5cb077ab3c88394b7ac8ed4e746bd31b53e39f1/Include/object.h#L359) and not for any arbitrary classes. For tpflag-check to work it must be set in C-code, like here (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9b648a95ccb4c3b14f1e87158f5c9f5dbb2f62c0/Objects/exceptions.c#L404)